# How to login SPA (Single page application) to custom rest api with Google Oauth

Tags: api, rest, symfony, cordova, oauth

we are building SPA and mobile app (spa with phonegap). We need to access/login/authenticate to our custom rest api build in Symfony2. Is it possible to login user with google oauth and then with google access_token authenticate to our API

Answer (score 0):

This is the flow for this use case: https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow

And after this you can use google token as your api token, or build your own oauth and use your own token.